# Error al parsear el JSON generado en el servidor

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

Hago una solicitud a un archivo php con AJAX. En este archivo traigo de mi base de datos (MySQL) un texto largo y lo guardo en un array PHP, luego lo paso a JS con `json_encode()`.

El problema que tengo es que hay veces que el texto lo muestra bien, otras veces que no muestra nada, lo manda vació. Sospecho que es cuando se juntan varios caracteres especiales.

Lo raro es que cuando tenía mi página en un servidor local con XAMPP no pasaba esto. El problema empezó cuando lo subí a un hosting gratuito.
El error que me aparece es:

> json parse error

Busqué en internet, leí muchas paginas y no pude solucionar el error. Les dejo el código del PHP y el AJAX.

El de PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT descripcion FROM localidades WHERE id_localidad='$id'";

$rs = mysql_query($sql);    

if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){
    while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        //son los campos
        $arr = array('descripcion'=>$fila[0], 'success'=>true);
        // $arr = array('descripcion'=> str_replace("\r\n", "\\n", $fila[8]), 'success'=>true);
    }
}else{
    $arr = array('success'=>false);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

y éste es el código JavaScript con el que hago la solicitud:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    param: id,
    param2: "descripcion"
  },
  url: "scripts/buscar_loc2.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(r) {
    //  var desc = eval ('(' + r.descripcion + ')');

    jQuery("#loc_desc").val(r.descripcion);

    //alert(desc);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
  }
});
```

Comment: "json parse error" normalmente sale en la consola. Ejecuta el Ajax, vete al network y busca el archivo .php al que le haces la petición, ahi ve a response y te va a decir el error mas especifico.

Comment: o tambien quita el "dataType:'json'", y console.log(r) a ver que es lo que trae el ajax

Comment: sigo sin solucionarlo...
Lo raro es que en localhost andaba... el problema es en el hosting...

Comment: no me da el error en donde decis...
me muestra el json pero en rojo, y al final cuando termina el json que cierra la }
me muestra un codigo javascript que es el de la publicidad del hosting... Sera esa publicidad lo que me esta dando problemas?

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos cómo obtienes el valor de la variable `$id` de tu código y qué te aparece en los campos enviados en el inspector de red de tu navegador y en el resultado? Es muy probable que éste saliendo algún tipo de advertencia PHP que corrompe la generación de los datos JSON. PD: Mejor si compartes el código PHP completo, pero vale si sólo agregas la parte que te comento.

Answer (score 1):

Es muy probable que tengas un error en tu código PHP que esté generando una advertencia (acceder a un índice no existente de una matriz, por poner un ejemplo) que corrompe el formato del JSON enviado al navegador.

Para intentar solucionar el problema podrías probar:

```
<?php
/* Poner esto JUSTO LO PRIMERO de todo tu código PHP */
ob_start();

/* ... Aquí iría el resto de tu código PHP ... */

$sql = "SELECT descripcion FROM localidades WHERE id_localidad='$id'";
$rs = mysql_query($sql);
$arr = array();   
if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0){
    while($fila=mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        //son los campos
        $arr = array('descripcion'=>$fila[0],
                    'success'=>true);
    //$arr = array('descripcion'=> str_replace("\r\n", "\\n", $fila[8]), 'success'=>true);
    }
}else{
    $arr = array('success'=>false);
}
/* Definimos la cabecera HTTP correcta */
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
/* Borramos cualquier mensaje de advertencia previo */
ob_end_clean();
/* Ahora enviamos al navegador la información correcta: */
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Con [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/ob_start) retengo y almaceno cualquier salida al navegador en un búffer. Con [`ob_end_clean()`](http://ob_end_clean) descarto cualquier salida previa (mensajes de advertencia).

Si quieres (te lo recomiendo) puedes obtener previamente su contenido y guardarlo en un archivo para su posterior análisis.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como te dijeron arriba mira que error da archivo.php en network con las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador.
Tambien agregale este header para que sepa el cliente que le responderas en formato json y con codificacion utf8 (por los caracteres especiales).
Suerte y saludos.

```
 header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: hola, habia probado con este header:
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

ahora pruebo con el que me pasaste y te comento! muchas gracias

Comment: no me funciono con ese header...